# what is the error of Error 126: Inconsistent structure definition 'unnamed' in C?

Tags: c, structure, lint

I am trying to link the my C code, and I got the following error message:

```
Error 126: Inconsistent structure definition 'unnamed'
```

there is no line number indicated which line has problems, and I do not have any structure of "unnamed", so I can not post the suspected code to here, have anyone experience this and how to fix it?

Comment: Inconsistent structure definition 'Symbol'  -- The named
       structure (or union or enum) was inconsistently defined across
       modules.  The inconsistency was recognized while processing a
       lint object module.  Line number information was not available
       with this message.  Alter the structures so that the member
       information is consistent.

Comment: Do you have a struct, enum or union called 'unnamed' defined in multiple headers?

Comment: Detailed description http://stellar.cleanscape.net/products/cpp/checks.html

Comment: I do not have any structure or union called "unnamed"

Comment: That isn't a "link" error, it is a "lint" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error 126: The named structure (or union or enum) was inconsistently defined
>   across modules.  The inconsistency was recognized while processing a
>   lint object module.  Line number information was not available with
>   this message.  Alter the structures so that the member information is
>   consistent.

Maybe a tagless struct bearing a tagless struct